# Trying to test latency on Jersey 2.0 (Async vs Sync)

Tags: java, rest, testing, jersey, netty

Even though stackoverflow has helped many times before, it is the first time I make a question. So enough sucking-up and lets get on to the issue :)

I am very new to RESTful services and even more to Jersey and I have been messing around with it for the past 3/4 weeks for a project and I have to questions that i really hope you can help me with:

The first one is if anyone knows a good and simple way to measure latency and requests/s with 1 or multiple clients since i have experienced that Jersey has a high latency and need some more concrete data to help me decide to which extent is it a good option for me.

The second question is more like a follow up to the first one. Knowing that Jersey invokes resources asynchronously I believe that is the cause for the high latency so I was trying to do Synchronously but I can't really understand the whole invocations that Jersey does. Does anyone have a solution for what I am trying to do or can at least explain to me the process in which Jersey invokes resources?

I believe this second question is a more complicated one to answer (since most people are probably using 1.12/13 until 2.0 is final) but any help would be greatly appreciated since i am a beginner and some concepts are a little out of grasp for me at the time being (will keep trying to learn though ;) )

Edit:
PS: i may have not mentioned it but i am using a netty4.0a2 container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) a try. It allows you to easily simmulate different scenarios of concurrent requests and load amounts and also has nice components for statistics summarization and visual analysis of the response times.